# Poor video & image quality in Ubuntu Studio 20.10 with Nvidia GTX 1050 ti

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, 20.10, kwin

**Problems with video playback (poor quality) and picture rendering (artefacts)**

Ubuntu Studio 20.10 installed from 5.8.0-25 low latency (Plasma 5.19.5 / KDE frameworks 5.74.0 / Graphics processor NV137 (X.org server driver)) + Nvidia GTX 1050ti

Compositor settings (default) : Precise scaling/ OpenGl 2.0 / vsync Auto

The rest of the graphics display fine (Ubuntu startup, logon & logout, thumbnails & icons, fonts, GUI), but pictures have artefacts and videos a bit blurry or bad (bits of still portions are moving randomly).

Youtube's 1080p videos look ugly with lots of artefacts. Other sites have better rendering but still not HD quality like on previous OS (Windows).

Tried changing driver to Nvidia 460 (driver, tested), but that produced resizing in logon/logout display and font sizes in apps + linked font scaling in Firefox with the desktop fonts.

Nvidia server driver 460 was better, but still caused desktop+apps font resizing and system failures.

Reverted to NV137 but problem still present.

***NOTE:** All driver changes from the driver manager caused system logout to fail (manual shutdown required) + login failure (not always, depending on compositor settings).*

**EDIT: (march 24)**
*Now a lot better with NV137 installed + system update to 5.8.0-48 low latency + adjusted compositor settings.
See my answer below.*

Comment: @Nmath Cleanup done. Hope it's better.

Comment: Probably related to this NEW question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328476/how-do-i-remove-an-installed-running-package-everything-related-in-ubuntu . If you can help with "sudo dpkg -r" please post Answer on that new question's page.

Answer (score 0):

BEST SOLUTION, UP TO NOW (march 24):

Image/video improved, but not 100%

Best driver for GTX 1050 ti / Ubuntu Studio 20.10 = NV137 from X.org server.

1. Rolled back to driver NV137 from Nvidia server driver 460 (better vid quality but bad system quality). It produced a logout failure (manual shutdown), login failure (logon screen disappeared, manual shutdown), restarted, logged in: login screen was black 10 secs and then desktop was OK.
2. Adjusted settings for compositor: Run at startup, Direct scaling (Smoothing degraded videos + login failure / Precise seems not supported = warning about my reported problems), engine GL3.1, vsync Auto.
3. There were system updates yesterday and today, maybe that helped, not sure.

Font display now fine in desktop and apps (Firefox, Thunderbird, etc), image/videos improved to 96-98% quality (no artefacts in images, though zooming in + moving image in sites like Pexels seem to leave a small trace behind). 4k looks good enough on my 1920X1080 monitor, 1080p now watchable (if 60ps better, else antialiasing seems off), 720p and below not very nice to watch.

Graphic display still a bit more grainy than previous OS + there seems to be a very feeble "flow" accross the screen (may be just an electric grounding problem in my appartment not related to problem).

A program called "Nvidia X server settings" was installed when I had Nvidia server driver, but now gone with NV137 installed. I still don't know how to configure settings to get 100% result with image/video.

I will edit when I find answer to that.

**EDIT (march 25):**

-Found this general resource about use of compositor:
https://dev.to/l04db4l4nc3r/compositors-in-linux-1hhb#configuring-the-compositor

Says: "it is NOT ideal during gaming" and causes latency but no info on video playback. NOT using compositor might lead to lack of vsync, needs to alter X11 config to ForceFullCompositionPipeline for Nvidia and compositor vsync turned off.

So, maybe not the solution, but may be useful info for gamers (not sure if Steam games like *GTA V* will run on Ubuntu Studio).

-Found this link for X server settings: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xorg/Guide

Will read it and edit if that resolves problem.