# How do I remove installed packages (and everything related to them) in Ubuntu Studio 20.10 using console?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall, software-uninstall

I'm only 3 weeks old in Ubuntu Studio 20.10, never used LINUX before.

**MY QUESTION:**

**Nvidia drivers** are still installed (current is X.org Server), probably why video quality is still not 100%.

For **VLC** packages, I'd like to remove safely all of them (they bug since install/removal of "win64" with Discover) before reinstall.

To remove those using "sudo dpkg -r", **not sure** how to format the whole command with pack name and options (remove everything related). The help section is not very clear for me and I haven't checked what the ***Purge*** function does.

**UPDATE**: the answer using "sudo apt remove --purge" worked for Nvidia, didn't need "sudo dpkg". Still looking for the other apps purge removal on the use of "~" (see answer)

Using **Discover** software manager got buggy results. I need a way to uninstall Discover. Found Discover's name was "plasma-discover", and 4 other packages start with same name adding stuff after a "-".

Also found "update-inetd", don't think I really need: I read it's used to MODIFY the inetd config file, and I only use Firefox for browsing and Thunderbird for mails. I would need to verify the inetd config for possible hacks (won't use ftp or samba (not installed but vlc-plugin-samba is in dpkg list)). Will ask a question about that and remove it from this one when answered.

**EDIT:**
Removed and reinstalled vokoscreenNG using "sudo snap install" and it upgraded from last version 3.0.5 to 3.0.8.

Now has the options I wanted but bugs: using "frame" I can't get drop-down menu to list size (only full screen size lists). It records in adjusted frame but doesn't stop recording, bringing back the voko window yields empty window, solution's to close it. Videos recorded seem ok but log has long error message relating to X.org server + app not keeping previous settings, maybe the Nvidia drivers conflicting with X.org drivers is source of problem? Hope removing Nvidia will fix this.

**UPDATE:** still working on this one.

Comment: That's a whole lot of questions packed into the space for a single one.  Sorry your computer got infected with something.  Maybe you would be better of reformatting and installing a clean version of Ubuntu?  To get rid of most/all of the nvidia drivers, try `sudo apt remove --purge ~nnvidia`

Comment: @Charles Green Less expensive opt is new pc, disinfection's too hard for me, needs specialized equipment, vendors/repair shops deny everything I say, won't fix it. I checked on Wikipedia (french & english) + web, it's a very nasty combo of rootkit/hacks on motherboard. Had already flashed BIOS but it kept wrong month date and logo of motherboard company was a bit different. Had no Windows anymore, Ubuntu Studio was only one I could get. Will prob reinstall on new Windows pc as altern OS, some apps are better than MS. But for Audio, I'll get back $$$$ of DAW and apps better than LINUX.

Comment: @Charles Green Thanks for understanding / much thanks for answer: will try it now , but want to check "nnvidia" with two N is NOT a typo? If not, and it doesn't solve issue with that, what about the "sudo dpkg -r" options (I found nvidia drivers using "dpkg --list", maybe it was there in "apt list", didn't check, I will do that first)?

Comment: It actually is two 'n's, and a tilda before them.

Comment: @Charles Green Thanks! It seemed to work, though only 10 packages were removed, a long list of packs weren't installed and could not be deleted + notes some libs would be replaced by others. Now, can I use 'sudo snap remove --purge ~n' followed by any package name I want to remove (if install made with snap, remove should be with snap I guess)?

Comment: I can't find info on web about use of '~n­' with package name when used with 'sudo apt remove --purge'... Say all is needed is package name...

Comment: I don't believe that it's a common thing among packages, but specific to the nvidia driver series.  I only know about it because I have an nvidia system, and am actually having a small issue with my laptop - the company which made it is arranging to have my system swapped out, I believe, so they can try to diagnose the oddity.

Comment: You might also take the time to `sudo apt autoremove --purge`

Comment: @Charles Green Thanks, If I understand well, to remove plasma-discover, I could enter 'sudo apt remove --purge plasma-discover' and it would remove all 5 plasma-discover packages? The ~ is not needed. Will try autoremove --purge. autoremove was ON, but not with purge.

Comment: The `purge` option removes the files from the disk after de-installation.   The seperate `autoremove` command removes packages which were installed automatically as dependancies of a package, but are no longer needed by any package on your system.   The combination of the two should remove all components of a package.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Charles Green helped solve the nvidia drivers removal.
All uninstalled now with this one command line in console:

*sudo apt remove --purge ~nnvidia*

Charles just told me the double n is nvidia specific. Still awaiting answer about the ~, will edit when I have it.